# What to do when documentation contribution is deleted several times?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I would like to discuss about what occurs on piece of documentation about [std::string Tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/488/stdstring/2148/tokenize).

From the edit history we can see :

- my initial [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/5365) add a simple example based on std::getline
- next severals contribution add new way to tokenize a string involving more modern C++ release and that's fine
- the initial sample was removed by this [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57032)
- my second [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/79417) restore the initial sample using std::getline
- the std::getline example was removed again by this [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97088)

Maybe the user that deleted twice my contribution think that it is useless to use old style method, and that everybody should use last C++ standard.

Should I re-edit the post ?
What do you think ?

Comment: Quote: "This crap doesn't belong here. There is already a question about this on the site, with more and better answers".  It is not like this leaves a lot to the imagination, does it?  What do you think it means?

Answer (score 1):

Garbage in, garbage out. Tokenize is a *terrible* example; it's way too big and is trying to do way too much. That entire "Strings" topic needs to be broken apart into about 5 actual topics.

If that were done, then we would have several examples about specific ways to tokenize a string. And thus, there would be no need for someone to try to remove your particular example.